# Пунктуация. Запятая

Tags: пунктуация, обстоятельство

**Магнитное поле — это особая форма материи, которая существует реально(,) независимо от нас.**

Нужна ли здесь запятая?
Эта конструкция рассматривается как уточняющая [реально — (как именно?) — независимо от нас]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Запятая нужна в любом случае.**

Мы выбираем тип отношений между обстоятельствами: **однородные, неоднородные, уточняющие/пояснительные.** Это точно не второй случай, а первый или третий, то есть оформление одинаковое ― постановка запятой.

Но вот семантика такого сообщения не очень ясна. Лучше написать: **независимо от нашего сознания.**

Comment: А еще точнее: существует объективно, независимо от нашего сознания

Comment: Да, это больше похоже на научную терминологию.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Не понятно, на кого рассчитана такая "научность". Всем и так известно, что материя - философская категория для обозначения объективной реальности, а объективная реальность - это то, что сушествует независимо от нашего сознания. В итоге имеем блин,  намасленный масляным маслом.

Comment: Надо знать цель написания статьи и для кого она предназначена. В данном случае отношения скорее однородные, они как бы повторяют (напоминают)  два определения из вашей фразы (объективность и независимость).

Answer (score 0):

Это не уточняющая, а пояснительная конструкция, запятая нужна.

Перед пояснительным членом предложения обычно стоят слова **именно, а именно, то есть (при отсутствии в предложении эти слова могут быть вставлены):**

> Ср.:Она была воспитана по-старинному, то есть окружена мамушками, нянюшками, подружками и сенными девушками (П.); Мы доехали на своих лошадях в возке, то есть в крытой рогожею повозке (Акс.); На другой день я с пятью якутами переправился через Лену, то есть через узенькие протоки, разделявшие бесчисленные острова (Гонч.);